# How do you run a kotlin file that accesses another file in vs code

Tags: kotlin

on vs code, i have a folder called master on my desktop with 2 kotlin files, `main.kt` and `foo.kt`.

`main.kt`'s code

```
import master

fun main() {
println("hello")
foo()
}
```

`foo.kt`'s code:

```
import master

fun foo(){
println("code from foo")
}
```

however, when i run `kotlinc hello.kt -d hello.jar` on the terminal of vs code, it says `error: unresolved reference: foo`

how can i resolve this? am i naming the packages wrong? I just want to run a very light kotlin package.